# Best to way to Run a Node JS script on Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, cron

First of all, "I'm noob"
My first time running some script on a cloud server.

So, I have a code that counts the number of views from my youtube vídeo and writes it in the title.
But I want that code running 24/7.

I make it works running on a VM instance on google cloud using cron-node running the code every 5 minutes and make it run forever with "forever" on the node.

And my question is: Have a better way to run it? Like using cloud functions or something? Or I should still run it on VM instance?
If yes, what should I do? Because I don't know how to use external dependencies on Cloud function like google API, if I don't have a console to install googleapi dependencies. (Maybe it's easy to make it, but I just don't know yet).

```
var readline = require('readline');
var { google } = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule("*/5 * * * *", () => {
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'update-youtube-title.json';

const youtube = google.youtube('v3');
const video_id = 'f0ARwVVxoBc';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), makeAuthCall);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
    });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
/*
function getChannel(auth) {
    var service = google.youtube('v3');
    service.channels.list({
        auth: auth,
        part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var channels = response.data.items;
        if (channels.length == 0) {
            console.log('No channel found.');
        } else {
            console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                'it has %s views.',
                channels[0].id,
                channels[0].snippet.title,
                channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
        }
    });
}
*/

//código novo


const makeAuthCall = (auth) => {
    //get views
    youtube.videos.list(
        {
            auth: auth,
            id: video_id,
            part: 'snippet,statistics'
        },
        (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`A contagem de views falhou ${err}`)
                return;
            }
            if (response.data.items[0]) {
                //atualização encontrada
                console.log('Encontramos uma atualização...');
                updateVideoTitle(response.data.items[0], auth);
            }
        }
    );
};

    const updateVideoTitle = (video, auth) => {
        let viewsText = video.statistics.viewCount.toLocaleString();
        const newTitle = `Esse Vídeo tem ${viewsText} Visualizações`;
        const oldTitle = video.snippet.title;

        if (newTitle != oldTitle){
        video.snippet.title = newTitle;
    
    
        console.log(`Atualizando contagem de views para ${viewsText}`);
     
        youtube.videos.update(
            {
                auth: auth,
                part: 'snippet,statistics',
                resource: video,
            },
            (err, response) => {
                console.log(response)
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`A contagem de views falhou ${err}`);
                    return;
                }
                if (response.data.items) {
                  console.log("Done");
                }
            
            }
        );
    }else{
      console.log("Atualização não necessária");
    };
}
})
```

Comment: It feels like you might be able to use Cloud Functions which runs NodeJS code when called.  If you combine that with Cloud Scheduler, you can then invoke that function on a regular basis.  I realize you are looking for a pre-canned solution or for help coding it up ... but hopefully these pointers may add some small value.

Comment: Do you need to run it full time, or a trigger every minute is enough?

Comment: every minute is enought

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad question with too much to unpack. Keep in mind the differences below are very simplistically explained and there could be more steps.

**Compute Engine/VM:**

- Step 1. Install javascript runtime (Nodejs) on the OS.
- Step 2. Put your code & dependencies

**Cloud Functions:**

- Step 1. Put your code & dependencies

**Summary:**

- Cloud Functions removes the need to manage the operating system and
  runtime. It might be easier for you. One way or another, you won't
  escape the need for your dependency setup.

**For Practice:**

- [These](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs) "quick start" articles will give an understanding of the setup process. You learn by doing with a "hello world" example.

**For Dependencies:**

- There is an article [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) that shows how to declare them in Cloud Functions. The sections of this article explains how you can load dependencies in different ways. The first example says: "*The dependency is then imported in the function*" and you see the part that says "***require('escape-html')***", it's the same as the "***escape-html": "^1.0.3***". This means that you can work backwards and see the requirements in your code to add them to your dependency manifest. But you may have to learn a bit more about the syntax by doing a Google search about package.json/npm and how it works in general.

**For Authentication:**

- Assuming your code is properly written, the "***require('googleapis')***" at the top of your code means that you should only need to add dependencies like mentioned previously and your code may be good to go for authentication.

**For Cron jobs:**

- In your code you are doing that by using "***const cron = require("node-cron");***" at the top of you code. This is like everything else I mentioned about dependencies and it's a software that triggers your code. I'm not sure if this will work like all other ones because Google has its own Cron jobs that work like [this](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub#create_a_job) (outside the Cloud Functions environment, but triggers the Cloud Functions on the network). Keep in mind that [this](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub#create_a_job) method could alter your code significantly. So if you can test with ***const cron = require("node-cron");*** dependencies, then do that first.

**Disclaimer:**

- Please open more specific questions if you can next time. Stackoverflow is not for consultation or broad questions with many follow-ups. It's more for coding answers to specific questions. Some may decide to close this post due to that.

Hope this helps.